# DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I developed a web application with ASP.NET MVC 4 and SQL Server 2008, I create ContextManager class to have only one database context in all pages.

```
public static class ContextManager
{
    public static HotelContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            var key = "Hotel_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x")
                      + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
            var context = HttpContext.Current.Items[key] as HotelContext;
            if (context == null)
            {
                context = new HotelContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = context;
            }
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

It works properly in most of the pages, but in registration page something goes wrong and my context gone deposed with following error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

```
public ActionResult Register ( RegisterModel model )
{
    if ( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount( model.UserName, model.Password,
                                              new
                                               {
                                                      Email = model.Email,
                                                      IsActive = true,
                                                      Contact_Id = Contact.Unknown.Id
                                               } );

            //Add Contact for this User.
            var contact = new Contact { Firstname = model.FirstName, LastName = model.Lastname };
            _db.Contacts.Add( contact );
            var user = _db.Users.First( u => u.Username == model.UserName );
            user.Contact = contact;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            WebSecurity.Login( model.UserName, model.Password );
```

at the line `_db.Contacts.Add( contact );` I got the exception.

But without using ContextManager by changing

```
HotelContext _db = ContextManager.Current;
```

into:

```
HotelContext _db = new HotelContext();
```

the problem was solved. But I need to use my own ContextManager. What is the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your context has been disposed somewhere else (not in the code you've shown), so basically when you access it from your `Register` action, it throws the exception.

Actually, you shouldn't use a static singleton to access to your context. **Do instantiate a new `DbContext` instance for each request**. See [c# working with Entity Framework in a multi threaded server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415955/c-sharp-working-with-entity-framework-in-a-multi-threaded-server/9416275#9416275)

Comment: the problem occours after creating the user and I also checked my db to be sure, WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount is proceeding successfully but at _db.Contacts.Add( contact ); i got the exception.

Comment: @ken2k, the ContextManager is storing the DbContext in HttpContext.Current.Items, so it is will be a new instance per request.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, my GetAll method was not calling ToList() method after where clause in lambda expression. After using ToList() my problem was solved.

```
Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are probably 'lazy-loading' a navigation property of `User` in your registration view. Make sure you include it by using the `Include` method on your `DbSet` before sending it to the view:

```
_db.Users.Include(u => u.PropertyToInclude);
```

Also, sharing `DbContext`s with a static property may have unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem. I solved it doing as it was said above. Instantiate a new instance of your context.

Try using this:

```
            using (HotelContextProductStoreDB = new ProductStoreEntities())
            {
                //your code
            }
```

This way it'll be created a new instance everytime you use your code and your context will not be disposed.

Answer (score 2):

Why override the Dispose(bool)?

```
public partial class HotelContext : DbContext
{
    public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        IsDisposed = true;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And, then check IsDisposed

```
public static class ContextManager
{
    public static HotelContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            var key = "Hotel_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x")
                      + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
            var context = HttpContext.Current.Items[key] as HotelContext;
            if (context == null || context.IsDisposed)
            {
                context = new HotelContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = context;
            }
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe, can be an option.