# Entity Framework 5 : Using Lazy Loading or Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm sorry if my question is normal. But I meet this problem when I design my ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Application using Entity Framework 5.

If I choose Eager Loading, I just simplify using :

```
public Problem getProblemById(int id) {
 using(DBEntity ctx = new DBEntity ())
            {
                return (Problem) ctx.Posts.Find(id);
            }
}
```

But if I use Eager Loading, I will meet problem: when I want to navigate through all its attributes such as comments (of problem), User (of Problem) ... I must manually use `Include` to include those properties. and At sometimes, If I don't use those properties, I will lost performance, and maybe I lost the strength of Entity Framework.

If I use Lazy Loading. There are two ways to use `DBContext` object. First way is using DBContext object locally :

```
public Problem getProblemById(int id) {
 DBEntity ctx = new DBEntity ();
 return (Problem) ctx.Posts.Find(id);
}
```

Using this, I think will meet memory leak, because ctx will never dispose again.

Second way is make DBContext object static and use it globally :

```
static DBEntity ctx = new DBEntity ();
public Problem getProblemById(int id) {
 return (Problem) ctx.Posts.Find(id);
}
```

I read some blog, they say that, if I use this way, I must control concurrency access (because multi request sends to server) by myself, OMG. For example this link :

[Entity Framework DBContext Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

So, how can design my app, please help me figure out.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Don't use a static `DBContext` object**. See [c# working with Entity Framework in a multi threaded server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415955/c-sharp-working-with-entity-framework-in-a-multi-threaded-server/9416275#9416275)

A simple rule for ASP.Net MVC: use a `DBContext` instance per user request.

As for using lazy loading or not, I would say **it depends**, but personally I would **deactivate lazy-loading**. IMO it's a *broken* feature because there are fundamental issues with it:

- **just too hard to handle exceptions**, because a SQL request can fail **at any place in your code** (not just in the DAL because one developer can access to a navigation property in *any* piece of code)
- poor performances if not well used
- too easy to write broken code that produces thousands of SQL requests

Comment: so, if i use Lazy Loading. How can i design my app to use DBContext object ? Thanks :)

Comment: I see many posts  (include MSDN link) that recommend not to use lazy loading. So, why microsoft still have this choices for programmers :( and they don't make any changes to make it easier to use :(

Comment: @hqt Using lazy loading or not won't change the way you use DBContext itself ; you'll still have to find a way to create a new instance per user request. A simple approach is to instantiate DBContext in the constructor of each controller, and pass it to the business layer. A more robust approach would be to use a IoC framework to automatically inject an instance of the context in each controller constructor using dependency injection. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-plus-N-ti for example

Comment: @hqt For the "why lazy loading is still a choice?" question, probably because it's easy to use a first glance and it looks powerful in all those "hello world" demos. But a lot of problems come quickly in a real world application because of it. I'm sure it's possible to use it correctly, but as a general rule, I would recommend to **not** use it unless you really know how it internally works.